# Get column groups that have a change in value in other column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataset, have a column with usernames and other column for their status.

```
username  status  
 John      TRUE
 John      TRUE
 John      FALSE
 Mike      FALSE
 ...        ...
```

I want to see if a user's status changes and who that user is. I don't know where to start, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.groupby('username')['status'].nunique().loc[lambda x: x.gt(1)].index
```

Comment: Maybe this would say if someone change status but I think it would get all the users that change status sometime in the past. I think what the question needs is the last update. Regards.

Comment: Thanks, this is enough for what i needed